# Book for learning Photoshop?

Tags: photoshop

I know this is not the right place to ask this but couldn't find a better one. Can anyone suggest me a good book to learn the Photoshop cs5 from basics to pro ?

Comment: Sorry, but this is a duplicate of a question that was _already_ closed as off topic.

Answer (score -1):

I like the book, [Real World Adobe Photoshop CS5 for Photographers [Paperback]](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321719832).